# Warning ao usar preg_match()

Tags: php, preg-match

Tive que migrar do PHP 5.2 para 5.3, então começaram a vir milhares de mensagens DEPRECATED no meu sistema PHP, porem alguns estão complicados demais, segue o código :

```
if (!preg_match($SUBMENU.':', $sm)) {
    $sm = explode($SUBMENU.":\n", $sm);
    $sm = trim(preg_replace('/[^(<ul>)]<\/ul>.*/s', "\\1\t</ul>", $sm[1]));
    $sm = str_replace(array('{URL_IMAGENS}', '{URL_SITE}'), array(URL_IMAGENS, URL_SITE), $sm);
    $mainTpl->assign('SUBMENU', $sm, 'STATIC');
}
```

Então recebo o erro:

> Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be
>   alphanumeric or backslash in /home/sisv2/public_html/adm/index.php on
>   line 135

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao usar expressões regulares no PHP como o [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php) devemos inserir um delimitador extra no nosso pattern. O seu erro é não usar delimitador nenhum:

```
if (!preg_match('/' . $SUBMENU .':/', $sm))
```